# Is app:srcCompat still needed with min Android support 5.0?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector drawable wrongly being shown completely white on Android 5.0.1 if I use android:src="@drawable/myicon", using app:srcCompat instead shows it correctly. I thought vector drawables are already supported on Android 5 and you don't need app:srcCompat anymore? I'm using it in an AppCompatActivity, here is the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="45dp"
    android:height="45dp"
    android:viewportWidth="40"
    android:viewportHeight="40">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M22.2222,31.1111l8.8889,0l0,-8.8889l-8.8889,0z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M8.8889,31.1111l8.8889,0l0,-8.8889l-8.8889,0z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M22.2222,17.7778l8.8889,0l0,-8.8889l-8.8889,0z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M0,40L40,40L40,0L0,0L0,40ZM4.4444,35.5556L35.5556,35.5556L35.5556,4.4444L4.4444,4.4444L4.4444,35.5556Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M8.8889,17.7778l8.8889,0l0,-8.8889l-8.8889,0z"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Did you add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in defaultConfig of build.gradle ?

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't be the cause anyways, that is only needed for srcCompat to work!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there are still many issues with vector drawables in some Android versions which get solved using app:srcCompat, at least using AppCompatActivity. I suppose the explanation is that using app:srcCompat a different code is used to process this property which may be addressing issues not addressed originally in the Android framework version.